# Xslt Exclude element by order

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML File :

```
<ID>
    <T1>
        <T2>XXXXX</T2>
        <T2>XXXXX</T2>
    </T1>
    <T3>
        <T4>
        <TxId>AAAXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
        </T4>       
        <T4>
        <TxId>BBBXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
        </T4>    
        <T4>
        <TxId>BBXXXXXXXXXXX</TxId>
        </T4>
    </T3>
    <T5>
        <T6>
        <Mod>gfh</Mod>
        </T6>
        <T6>
        <Mod>fhg</Mod>
        </T6>
        <T6>
        <Mod>fgh</Mod>
        </T6>
    </T5>
</ID>
```

I need to exclude T4 element when 3 first char of TxId = AAA
If i exclude the first T4 i must exclude the first T6 , if 6th T4 element is excluse i need to exclude 6th T6 element.

I have tried that :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T4[starts-with(TxId,'AAA')]">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T4"/> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i have no idea how to join T4/T6 exclusion
Thank you

Comment: The element names in your XSLT are not consistent with those in your example XML, can you fix one or the other?

Comment: Is that ALL that links the two: their position in the parent element? Note also that your stylesheet doesn't match the question or the XML (OrgnlTx vs. T4, SOP vs. AAA).

Comment: There is no link like an ID or other , it's just the position : if i exclude T4 element Number N i need to excluse T6 element number N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="t4" match="T4" use="count(preceding-sibling::T4)" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T4[starts-with(TxId,'AAA')]"/>  
<xsl:template match="T6[starts-with(key('t4', count(preceding-sibling::T6))/TxId,'AAA')]"/> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T4[starts-with(TxId, 'AAA')] | 
                     T6[../../T3/T4[starts-with(TxId, 'AAA')] and count(preceding-sibling::T6) = count(../../T3/T4[starts-with(TxId, 'AAA')]/preceding-sibling::T4)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then as long as there is only a single `T3` and `T5` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a good start by basing your transform on the identity template.  What I would do here is create a template matching all T6 elements and then have that delegate to the identity template for the items you *don't* want to exclude

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- exclude T4 that start with AAA -->
<xsl:template match="T4[starts-with(TxId, 'AAA')]" />

<xsl:template match="T6">
  <!-- save our position in the parent's list of child nodes - thanks to the
       strip-space this will match the position of the corresponding T4 within
       its parent -->
  <xsl:variable name="mypos" select="position()" />

  <xsl:if test="starts-with(../../T3/T4[$mypos]/TxId, 'AAA')">
    <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the positions don't necessarily line up that precisely (remember `position()` is sensitive to exactly what `apply-templates select` expression caused this template to fire, so will break if the `T5` has any attributes or any other children besides the `T6` elements) then it may be safer to say

```
<xsl:variable name="mypos" select="count(preceding-sibling::T6) + 1" />
```